# What dos this Ruby statement mean?

Tags: ruby, file, rubygems

The code below comes from the documentation for the Ruby Gem rroc. I desperately need to calculate the AUC for my AI project.  However I have virtually no knowledge of Ruby file I/O, not having had occasion to learn. The documentation says rroc expects an n by 2 array but the first line of code below suggest that the data is in a csv file and it will be formatted into my_data for roc to calculate the auc.

I have tried every conceivable combination of csv data and arrays as both files for the first line to read or direct input into the line calculating auc. At best the code works, without error but gives a useless output of 0.  My hope is that if I had a fuller understand of what that line does, I could either fix the problem or give up on the gem since a previous version of this gem was shown to be obsolete and this one's 8 years old. I took the data from the article referenced by the gem author and am pretty sure it's not the problem, but then,...

So, to refine the question: from that statement, can we tell what kind of data should be in 'some_data.cvs'? And what will be done to it to make my_data?

```
require 'rroc'

my_data = open('some_data.csv').readlines.collect { |l| l.strip.split(",").map(&:to_f) }
auc = ROC.auc(my_data)
puts auc
```

Below I've copied the output for two runs, the first with array data read in, the second with csv values (each in separate files). I added a line to read out the input file just to be sure.

```
RoyiMac:ruby $ ruby PDaucT.rb
[[90, 1], [80, 1], [70,-1], [60,1], [55,1], [54,1], [53,-1], [52,-1], [51,1], [50,-1], [40,1], [39,-1], [38,1], [37,-1], [36,-1], [35,-1], [34,1], [33,-1], [30,1], [10,-1]] 

0.0
RoyiMac:ruby $ ruby PDaucT.rb
90,1,80,1,70,-1,60,1,55,1,54,1,53,-1,52,-1,51,1,50,-1,40,1,39,-1,38,1,37,-1,36,-1,35,-1,34,1,33,-1,30,1,10,-1

0.0
```

Comment: It'd be just as quick to just run each chunk of code in the REPL to see what it's creating, no? (It's weird to use both `collect` and `map`, but that's secondary.) I mean, hopefully `readlines` is pretty self-explanatory, and `collect`/`map` are pretty typical operations. What specifically is the issue with the code other than whatever `auc` is isn't providing the result you think you should get?

Comment: This code does naive CSV parsing. The proper way is with the [built-in CSV module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Comment: Please take a moment to write a new title for your question. This title is completely generic and gives no insight into what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically: _"The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. So make it count."_

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of those methods, and which parts of the code you *do* and *don't* understand. Do you know what a variable is? Do you know what a message send is? Do you know what an assignment is? Do you know what an argument list is? Do you know what a block is? Do you know what a parameter list is? Do you know what a string is? Do you know what a float is? Do you know what a constant is? And so on. For one, this will allow us to focus our answers. And second, this will allow the Ruby developers to …

Comment: … improve the documentation, so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. Help make the world a better place!

Answer (score 1):

The explanation of the code:

```
open('some_data.csv') # open the some_data.csv file
  .readlines          # returns an array with each element being a line
  .collect { |l|      # for each line do the following tranformation
    l.strip           # remove proceeding and trailing whitespace characters
     .split(',')      # split the line based on the "," character (returning an array)
     .map(&:to_f)     # call .to_f on each element in the array, converting them to a float value
  }
```

`map`/`collect` are aliases of each other.

However, like tadman already said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398484/what-dos-this-ruby-statement-mean#comment103143618_58398484) you're better of using the [csv](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) standard library. The same can be achieved with:

```
require 'csv'

my_data = CSV.read('some_data.csv', converters: :float)
# should output
#=> [[90, 1], [80, 1], [70,-1], [60,1], [55,1], [54,1], [53,-1], [52,-1], [51,1], [50,-1], [40,1], [39,-1], [38,1], [37,-1], [36,-1], [35,-1], [34,1], [33,-1], [30,1], [10,-1]]
```

Comment: When I read your response it wasn't clear to me how the code you translated for me would produce and array like the one you show in the standard library example.  I then copied your csv code, fed it a text file exactly like the second one in my copied output above and it returned the a vertical listing of the numbers, one per line.
I then used the original line in question and it, too, printed out a vertical listing, one number per line.  So it seems to me to remain unclear what roc needs and, if it needs an array, how it gets one given the code provided.

Comment: @Roy I don't have any experience with the roc-curve, but the library also offers `ROC.curve_points(my_data)`, you could check if that yields any results.

Comment: that's a separate method that plots the ROC curve itself.  Interesting but not what I need.

Comment: You say that, but both `auc` and `curve_points` call the same method. https://github.com/stevenbedrick/RROC/blob/b0352dc3e6d8a1ded11a244000c7a9a9ed38ed77/lib/rroc.rb#L15-L28